# Cannot get stripe charge work with app engine Golang

Tags: google-app-engine, go, stripe-payments

So here is my problem, i have been following the github readme for app engine users in order to implement stripe into my app but the thing is that i can’t make it work as it seems that the http.DefaultTransport and http.DefaultClient are not available in App Engine.

I have seen that in the readme you show us how to initialize the Stripe client with app engine but i cannot find any charge card example so this is why i have come to this implementation.

I am used to this problem, since i have been working with app engine for a long time but for some reason i still get this akward error :

`cannot use stripe.BackendConfiguration literal (type stripe.BackendConfiguration) as type stripe.Backend in assignment: stripe.BackendConfiguration does not implement stripe.Backend (Call method has pointer receiver)`

Here is the code :

```
func setStripeChargeClient(context context.Context, key string) *charge.Client {
    c := &charge.Client{}

    var b stripe.Backend
    b = stripe.BackendConfiguration{
        stripe.APIBackend, 
        "https://api.stripe.com/v1",
        urlfetch.Client(context),
    }

    c.Key = key
    c.B = b

    return c
}
```

Getting the error on that b assignation …

What i can’t figure it out is why this example seems to work all around the web and does not work in my app, if you could please enlighten me on this one, i would be in your debt hahaha

and then calling it this way

`stripeClient := setStripeChargeClient(context, "sk_live_key »)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally got the solution by doing so :

```
func setStripeChargeClient(context context.Context, key string) *charge.Client {
       c := &charge.Client{}

       //SETTING THE CLIENT WITH URL FETCH PROPERLY
       fetch := &http.Client{
              Transport: &urlfetch.Transport{
              Context: context,
        },
       }

     //USE SetHTTPClient method to switch httpClient
     stripe.SetHTTPClient(fetch)

     var b stripe.Backend
     b = &stripe.BackendConfiguration{stripe.APIBackend, 
     "https://api.stripe.com/v1",fetch}

     c.Key = key
     c.B = b

     return c
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution as per Stripe's GAE recommendations:

```
func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    myStripeKey := "pk_test_ABCDEF..."
    httpClient := urlfetch.Client(c)
    stripeClient := client.New(myStripeKey, stripe.NewBackends(httpClient))
    chargeParams := &stripe.ChargeParams{
        Amount:    uint64(totalCents),
        Currency:  "usd",
        Desc:      description,
        Email:     email,
        Statement: "MyCompany",
    }
    chargeParams.SetSource(token)
    charge, chargeErr := stripeClient.Charges.New(chargeParams)
```